# why are my static files failing to load response

Tags: node.js, express

i am trying to get data from a html form using express
but when i try to load my static files with app.use(express.static(__dirname+"public");
in the devtools it is showing that it failed to load my response data
can anyone tell me why this is happening and a solution for this
[image]

[image]

here is the code in the first image

```
 const express = require('express');

 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 const app = express();




app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'public'));


app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/bmiCalculator.html");
});

app.post("/",function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("hello");
});


app.listen(300,function(){
  console.log("Server Hosted OK");
});
```

Comment: Please add code instead of pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path provided to the static middleware is incorrect. The following code `__dirname+'public'` will give you `Calculatorpublic`, i.e. `/` is missing. What you can do is to add the `/` before `public`:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname, "/public"));
```

Another variation:

```
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

Comment: thank you sir i was so confused as to where i was wrong but it turned out that this small mistake was doing that